# Pytest, How to make a temporary drive in a different location other than C drive: Windows

Tags: python, pytest

I am trying to create a temporary directory in a drive other than the C Drive using pytest.

The normal way to create a temporary drive ac according to my knowledge is as below:

```
@pytest.fixture
def copy_path_file(qtbot, request, tmpdir):
    """Setup Project widget."""
    directory = request.node.get_marker('change_directory')
    if directory:
        project_dir = to_text_string(tmpdir.mkdir('project'))
    else:
        project_dir = None
```

The temporary drive using this method is created in drive C. of the windows system drive, but I want to create a temporary drive in D, for example.

Does anyone have experience with pytest? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [pytest documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/tmpdir.html#the-default-base-temporary-directory):

> ### The default base temporary directory
>
> Temporary directories are by default created as sub-directories of the
>   system temporary directory. The base name will be `pytest-NUM` where `NUM`
>   will be incremented with each test run. Moreover, entries older than 3
>   temporary directories will be removed.
>
> You can override the default temporary directory setting like this:
>
> `pytest --basetemp=mydir`
>
> When distributing tests on the local machine, `pytest` takes care to
>   configure a basetemp directory for the sub processes such that all
>   temporary data lands below a single per-test run basetemp directory.